# Direct ssh tunnel through a reverse SSH tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh

I have 3 PCs:

- A is behind a firewall and cannot be reached from outside the local network
- B is outside the A network, has a public DNS but cannot see A
- C is a laptop without public DNS that often changes IP

I would like to create a reverse ssh tunnel from A to B in order to allow C to reach A passing through B. I read some guides and followed the procedure, but i'm doing something wrong.

I try to recap what've done.

Doing this on A

```
ssh -Nfg -R 2210:localhost:22 userB@B
```

allows me to reach A from B doing on B

```
ssh -p 2210 userA@localhost
```

To reach A from C I can do on C

```
ssh userB@B
ssh -p 2210 userA@localhost
```

Until now everything looks great. Now I would like to connect from C to A directly. This is not laziness, but is (i think) required to use FileZilla from C to A.

I go back to step 1 and do on A:

```
ssh -Nfg -R :2210:localhost:22 userB@B
```

(note the ":" before 2210)

I also edited the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on B adding at the end.

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

But doing on C

```
ssh -p 2210 userA@B
```

returns a timeout error.

Where I do wrong?

Thank you very much

PS: also another way to open the tunnel and allow FileZilla to connect from C to A would be ok.

Comment: Is ssh -Nfg -R :2210:logalhost:22 userB@B what you are actually doing or is this a typo meaning ssh -Nfg -R :2210:localhost:22 userB@B

Comment: What does a `netstat -tulpen` on B shows? Is port 2210 accessible from external or just from localhost? Please paste the related line here.

Comment: @Elder Geek: it was a typo inside the post. Sorry and congratulation for the attention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved thanks to Lars Noodén on UbuntuForum [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2269988#2)

I report the solution for future readers:

> You have created a reverse tunnel from port 22 on A to port 2210 on B. 
>   Add a regular tunnel from any port on C (e.g. 2212) to port 2210 on B.
>
> `ssh -L 2212:localhost:2210 userB@hostB`
>
> Then on C you can point FileZIlla, or any other SFTP client, at port 2212 on the localhost and it will be connecting to A.

Using this solution I can easily do `ssh -p 2212 userA@localhost` on C to connect directly to A from C. Furthermore I can use the port 2212 on localhost for all the services I need to connect from C to A that doesn't allow tunnels (e.g. Filezilla).